# Flask-seeder initial data, why faker.create does not print anything in console?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, seed

I have to set initial data in my app by using flask-seeder - https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Seeder/.
When I run command flask seed run i get in my console this information

```
Running database seeders
Committing to database!
```

it does not print what was created, but in my code there is line which says that it should print. The result in console should look like this:

```
Running database seeders
Adding Virtual Assistant: id=1, Name=Marek, last_name=Krol, job=teacher, image_filename=me.jpg, image_url=thispersondoesnotexist.com
DemoSeeder... [OK]
Committing to database!
```

It is first time when I am trying to do something like this and I do not know what is wrong.

```
class DemoSeeder(Seeder):
    def run(self):
        faker = Faker(
            cls = VirtualAssistant,
            init={
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Marek",
                "last_name": "Krol",
                "job": "Teacher",
                "image_filename": "me.jpg",
                "image_url": "thispersondoesnotexist.com"
            }
        )
        for assistant in faker.create(1):
            print("adding Virtual Assistant: %s" % assistant)
            self.db.session.add(assistant)
```

My model

```
class VirtualAssistant(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    job = db.Column(db.String(30))
    image_filename = db.Column(db.String)
    image_url = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self, name, last_name, job, image_filename, image_url):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.job = job
        self.image_filename
        self.image_url
    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None, last_name=None, job=None, image_filename=None, image_url=None):
        self.id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        self.name = db.Column(db.String(30), name)
        self.last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), last_name)
        self.job = db.Column(db.String(30), job)
        self.image_filename = db.Column(db.String, image_filename)
        self.image_url = db.Column(db.String, image_url)

    def __str__(self):
        return "id=%d, name=%s, last_name=%s, job=%s, image_filename=%s, image_url=%s" % (self.id, self.name, self.last_name, self.job, self.image_filename, self.image_url)
```

Solution: for anyone who read this the issue here was that i did not have seeds directory with demo.py file, everything was in the same file app.py what is wrong.

Comment: This line "Adding Virtual Assistant: id=1, Name=Marek, last_name=Krol, job=teacher, image_filename=me.jpg, image_url=thispersondoesnotexist.com" is what is being printed by faker.create in the console

Comment: no I mean this is how it should look,but it does not, for now what it is, is only Running database seeders
Committing to database!

Comment: My bad, I didnt see the line above it clearly. @LuiTe

Comment: it is fine, do you know what can be issue?

Comment: Of the top of my head, no I do not know what the issue is. But here are somethings you could try. Double check your class "VirtualAssistant" and ensure that it follows the following format in this link https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Seeder/ . You want to look at seed/demo.py . Also if you provide an [MRE] , I could try to run and debug on myend

Comment: I have checked this code many times actually, I am struggling with this issue some days. I have added my model to question, maybe you can take a look at this now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214904/discussion-between-luite-and-akib-rhast).